# How to join same column twice?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I'm building a trading site and have these tables

Example:

The First one is fruit.

```
+----+--------+
| ID |  Name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Apple  |
|  2 | Orange |
|  3 | Banana |
+----+--------+
```

The Second one is the trading

```
+-----+-------+--------+-------+
| tID | first | second | third |
+-----+-------+--------+-------+
|   1 |     2 |      1 |     3 |
|   2 |     3 |      1 |     2 |
+-----+-------+--------+-------+
```

I want to join them into a table show that whats the first/second/third means , like

```
+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+--------+
| tID | first |   n1   | second |  n2   | third |   n3   |
+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|   1 |     2 | Orange |      1 | Apple |     3 | Banana |
|   2 |     3 | Banana |      1 | Apple |     2 | Orange |
+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Here is my sql

```
SELECT trade.tid ,trade.first , fruit.name AS n1,trade.second ,     
fruit.name AS n2,trade.third , fruit.name AS n3
FROM trade 
INNER JOIN fruit 
ON trade.first=fruit.id
INNER JOIN fruit 
ON trade.second=fruit.id
INNER JOIN fruit 
ON trade.third=fruit.id
```

And I got the response is

```
Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'card'
```

What should I do ? Is my sql wrong or the database should not store data like this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use aliases on the tables.  This is generally a good idea, and it is necessary when you have the same table multiple times in the `from`:

```
SELECT t.tid, t.first, f1.name AS n1, t.second, f2.name AS n2,
       t.third, f3.name AS n3
FROM trade t LEFT JOIN
     fruit f1
     ON t.first = f1.id LEFT JOIN
     fruit f2 
     ON t.second = f2.id LEFT JOIN
     fruit f3
     ON t.third = f3.id;
```

Notice that I also changed the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.  This is handy in case some of the rows are missing "fruit" values.  Also, the table aliases are abbreviations of the table names, making the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: `t1.name AS n1` that should be `f1.name AS n1` I think.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all *(except for the fact that there is no `card` table or alias in the code you posted)*: there are three instances of the `fruit` table and `MySQL` cannot tell them apart.

You need to use aliases for them in the `FROM`/`JOIN` clause and use the aliases instead of the table names in the rest of the query:

```
SELECT
  trade.tid,
  trade.first,  fruit1.name AS n1,
  trade.second, fruit2.name AS n2,
  trade.third,  fruit3.name AS n3
FROM trade 
  INNER JOIN fruit fruit1 ON trade.first  = fruit1.id
  INNER JOIN fruit fruit2 ON trade.second = fruit2.id
  INNER JOIN fruit fruit3 ON trade.third  = fruit3.id
```